# Really cool iOS rotation animation

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

Can anyone show me an example of a cool animation when an iOS device is rotated? I have the following method implemented in my UIViewController:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

and I want to be able to make things fly around in a cool way, not just the standard rotation. I've never dealt with animations, so if someone could show me an example (or give me a link to a website with examples) of a neat animation, that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have a hard time getting help implementing large amounts of code when you haven't shown much effort into trying it on your own first. You should start with the [animation guides](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Graphics_iPhone/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007300) Apple provides, and try building some basic animations of your own. Once you have an idea of what specific animations you need help with, getting help on SO will be easy.